# Rest web service consuming JSON using Jersey and ExtJS

Tags: java, json, rest, extjs, jersey

I'm trying to implement the Jersey framework in order to route our client requests using the restful approach. I have successfully created methods that read primitive parameters, send them and they can even respond with a JSON from an object. However the one thing I have not been able to do is read (i.e. consume) a json object from a post/put or even get request. I've tried everything I can find online but to no avail. Because of some work issues I am confined using Java 6 and Jersey 1.19. Also for our client side stuff we're using ExtJS.

My ExtJS request is formatted as so:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'rest/RestClass/getMessage',
method: 'PUT',
header: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
jsonData: {
    status: {
        id: 1,
        description: 'Description'
    }
},
success: function(response) {
    var result = response.responseText;
},
failure: function(response) {
    Ext.Msg.alert('Communication Error', 'Failed');
}
});
```

As far as my back end stuff goes I have this:

```
@PUT
@Path("/getMessage")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void getMsg(JAXBElement<Status> status) {
    System.out.println("status id = " + status.getValue().getId());
    System.out.println("status description = " + status.getValue().getDescription());
}
```

Also my Status object is:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Status{

    private int id;
    private String description;

    public Status() {

    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

I have properly mapped the jersey servlet etc since I've already sent successful requests. My problem is when I try to send one with a json object in the parameters I get errors.

At first I was getting as error for a missing `jackson` library even though I am using `jersey-bundle-1.19.jar` which supposedly contains everything needed. After downloading `jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar` and adding it to the project I am now getting this error:

> A message body reader for Java class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement, and
>   Java type
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement,
>   and MIME media type application/json was not found.

I even added some `jaxb` jars just in case but still getting the same error. Many examples I've seen online didn't work for me. Also they all use maven for dependency control which we do not have access to so I cannot be sure we are using the same libraries...

What I'm looking for here is a solution with the things I have available:
jersey 1.19
ExtJS 5
JDK 6
WebLogic 10.X

The goal is to be able to send an request with a JSONObject as parameter and have it be decoded server side into an existing object type.

EDIT: I even added POJO mapping in my web.xml (i found online it is needed for jersey to support json/object mapping)

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Still have the same problem. The client gives me a `415 error for unsupported media type`

Comment: Why are you sending a JAXBElement<Status> type? It should be Status only. Like: public void getMsg(Status status). You don't also need the annotation: @XmlRootElement

Comment: Because all the examples I saw had these annotations. I finally found the answer and yes it doesn't need those annotations. However it needs the @JsonCreator annotation on my model's constructor.

Comment: Since I leaded you to the resolution, and least you can put an upvote! Don't u think? :)

Comment: I actually found the solution earlier (I even changed the libraries for no reason apparently) but since SO works on "reputation" which has no meaning whatsoever I don't mind up voting anyone for any reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. There are several changes that need to be made:

In the jsonData object of the request there shouldn't be a `status` root property. Just the object itself:

```
jsonData: {
    id: 1,
    description: 'Description'
},
```

Also I removed the `JAXBElement<Status>` from my method's declaration. It just receives a `Status status` object.

Finally the `Status class` doesn't need the `@XmlRootElement` annotations. It needs however the `@JsonCreator` annotation over its default (empty) constructor.